# react functional components call child component method

Tags: reactjs, react-forwardref

I have **ModalPopup** component as a parent and I am rendering **cart** and **orderform** as child components based on some conditions. For each component I have separate buttons in **modalPopup** which gets rendered once child **componenent** is changed in the **modalPopUp**.

I want to call **orderForm** component method from **ModalPopUp** component on **place order** button click.

While placing order getting below error in console.

***index.js:1 Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?***

```html
<ModalPopUp 
  show={isModalVisible} 
  hide={hideModal} 
  onCheckout={cartCheckout}
  onOrderPlaced={placeOrder}>
      {
       isCheckoutDone? <OrderForm ref={orderFormRef}/> :<Cart selectedProducts={selectedProducts}/>
      }
 </ModalPopUp>
```

Refer [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-yjhrcf?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FSearchProduct%2FSearchProduct.js) code here.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to follow the warning? Visiting the docs gives you an example

Comment: I am new to react I find the document but confusing.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to use `forwardRef` along with `useImperativeHandle`

https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef

https://react.dev/reference/react/useImperativeHandle

```
import { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle, useRef } from 'react';

const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, { func: () => { ... } }, []);

  return (...);
});

const Parent = () => {
  const childRef = useRef(null);

  const handleOnSomething = () => {
    if (childRef.current) {
      childRef.current.func();
    }
  }

  return (
    <Child ref={childRef} onSomething={handleOnSomething} />
  )
}
```

Comment: I am getting childRef as undefined because my orderForm component is rendering condtionally.

Comment: If it isn't rendered then you won't be able to use it. You'll either have to skip it or provide a default implementation.

Comment: Ok I tried using usedynamicref library but that didn't work

Comment: Using one modal pop up to render two components Conditionally. Is this wrong implementation?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with doing that. What is unnecessary is the use of refs to call child methods from the parent. The child method and any necessary state should probably be moved into the parent.