# Unable to Trigger Click Events on Save Buttons Within Child Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm encountering an issue with simulating click events on save buttons within child components in my React application.

I have a parent component called AddQuestionsPage where I render multiple instances of a child component called Question. Each Question component contains an input field and a save button to save the question.

My goal is to trigger a click event on the save button of each Question component when the user clicks on the "Finish Quiz" button in the AddQuestionsPage component.

I've tried using refs to access the save buttons within the Question components and simulate click events, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. The click events are not being triggered, and the questions are not being saved.

I've verified that the refs are being properly assigned to the save buttons, but for some reason, the click events are not being fired when I call buttonRef.current?.click() within the handleSaveAllQuestions function.

```
// AddQuestionsPage component
// Renders multiple Question components
// Handles saving questions
// Should trigger save button clicks on child Question components
function AddQuestionsPage() {
  const saveButtonRefs = useRef([]);

  const handleSaveAllQuestions = async () => {
    try {
      await Promise.all(
        saveButtonRefs.current.map(async (buttonRef) => {
          await buttonRef.current?.click();
        })
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error saving questions:", error);
    }
  };

  const handleFinishQuiz = async () => {
    try {
      await handleSaveAllQuestions();
      console.log("Quiz finished");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error finishing quiz:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Render multiple Question components */}
      {questions.map((question, index) => (
        <Question
          key={index}
          saveButtonRef={(ref) => (saveButtonRefs.current[index] = ref)}
        />
      ))}
      <button onClick={handleFinishQuiz}>Finish Quiz</button>
    </div>
  );
}

// Question component
// Contains an input field and a save button
// Should save the question when the save button is clicked
function Question({ saveButtonRef }) {
  const handleSaveQuestion = async () => {
    try {
      // Save the question logic...
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error saving question:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" />
      <button ref={saveButtonRef} onClick={handleSaveQuestion}>
        Save
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've checked for errors and ensured that all components are properly rendered and functional. Is there something I'm missing or misunderstanding about how refs and click events work in React?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React events are synthetic. They are not the same thing as native javascript events. The `handleSaveQuestion` callback cannot be called by firing `element.click()`.

See issue #2 in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43569630/23555538

You will need to fire the actual callback, rather than trying to trigger it through `element.click()`. There are a couple ways you could achieve this, but you should definitely be following the react principle of [lifting state up](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components).

I would probably move the `handleSaveQuestion` functionality into the `addQuestionsPage` component and keep the question text as state within your questions object. Pass that to the `Question` component, as well as a callback to change the question text.

You could also use `forwardRef` (which you should probably be doing here anyways) with `useImpererativeHandle` to pass the callback back to the parent component.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66400395/23555538